# Why exactly does proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty} {f(n)\over g(n)} = 0$ also proves that ${f(n) < g(n)}$, being that $f$ and $g$ are functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I've been doing this kind of proof in my calculus classes a lot while working with sequences and series, but I never really understood why this holds true. I specially had to do this to prove that $$\ln(n) < n < n\ln(n) < n^c <...$$ and that $$\ln(n) < n^{c/2}$$ for any $c > 0$.

Comment: Think about it.  If a fraction is close to zero, it's really small, which means the denominator is bigger than the numerator

Comment: Wait, is it just that? I thought it was more complicated than that :p Thank you!

Comment: Technically, these inequalities only hold *as of* a given $n$, not for all $n$.

Comment: True. But for things like the direct comparison test for convergence (since I'm working with series after all), isn't "holding true as of a given $n$" already enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $g$ is a strictly positive function (or at least that $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N:g(n)>0$, where equality with $0$ is excluded in order to assure that we do not divide by $0$ taking the limit).

If $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$, then by definition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N:\left|{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}\right|<\epsilon :=1$. In particular, $\forall n \geq N: \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<1$, i.e. $\forall n \geq N: f(n)<g(n)$. Hence, at some point, $f$ lies under $g$.

Note that this is false when we do not suppose that $g$ is a positive function, for example take $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=-x^2$.

Comment: The $\epsilon$ can be defined as $1$ because definition of limit states that it can be any positive number, right? I've been confused in that regard.

Comment: @Carmo This is correct!

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$, then there is a $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\left\lvert\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right\rvert<1.$$But then$$n\geqslant N\implies\bigl\lvert f(n)\bigr\rvert<\bigl\lvert g(n)\bigr\rvert.$$In particular, if $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f(n)\geqslant0$,$$n\geqslant N\implies f(n)<g(n).$$

Answer (score 1):

By definition of limits, if $f(n)/g(n)\to 0$ then there exists an $N$ such that $f(n)/g(n)<1$ for all $n>N$. Hence if $g(n)$ is positive, this equivalent to $f(n)<g(n)$ for all $n>N$.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are great, but if you want a simple example of why this is true consider $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = x$ then it follows that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$ which proves that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x) > \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$$ by what you have already said. To see why this is true, I have graphed both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and $f(x)/g(x)$ in Desmos for you. Notice that as the limit of each function approach $\infty$, it is clear that $g(x)$ is growing faster than $f(x)$. Then notice that $1/x$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$. Here is the link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t8qecgay74

Comment: I appreciate the example, but I wanted a way of proving that'd work for any positive f(x) and g(x). This really helped make it easier to visualize, though. Thank you :D